# how to resolve "cannot read property appendChild of null" in the following code?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-synthesis

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> speech synthesizer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="voiceinator">
      <h1> My Speech Synthesizer </h1>

      <select id="voices" name="voice">
        <option value="">Select a voice</option>
      </select>

    <label for="rate">Rate:</label>
    <input type="range" name="rate" value="1" min="0" max="3" step="0.1">

    <label for="pitch">Pitch:</label>
    <input type="range" name="pitch" min="0" max="2" step="0.1">

    <textarea name="text"> Hello there! </textarea>
    <button type="button" id="stop"> Stop! </button>
    <button type="button" id="speak"> Speak </button>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  let voices = [];
  var voicesDropdown = document.querySelector('[name="voices"]');
  const options = document.querySelector('[name="range"], [name="text"]'); // this selects the rate control bar, pitch bar and text area
  const speakButton = document.querySelector('#speak');
  const stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop');
  msg.text = document.querySelector('[name="text"]').value;

  function populateVoices()
  {
    voices = this.getVoices();

    for( var i=0 ; i<voices.length ; i++ ){
      var opt = voices[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      voicesDropdown.appendChild(el);
    }

  }
  //when speechSynthesis loads , voiceschanged event occurs and populateVoices function is fired
  speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', populateVoices);
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING --- HOW TO RESOLVE IT?

> SPEECH SYNTHESIZER.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
>       at SpeechSynthesis.populateVoices (SPEECH SYNTHESIZER.html:45)

Also please tell me how do I append two values to el.textContent? For eg. I want it to display `voices[i].name` and `voices[i].lang`

Comment: probably because name is voice and not voices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` on the `<select>` is `voice` not `voices`. But simpler and more efficient to get that element by ID

Change:

```
var voicesDropdown = document.querySelector('[name="voices"]');
```

To

```
var voicesDropdown = document.querySelector('#voices');
```

Comment: can you please also tell me how do i append two values to el.textContent? For eg. i want it to display voices[i].name and voices[i].lang..

Comment: try `var opt = voices[i].name +' -- ' +voices[i].lang`

Answer (score 0):

1. > THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING --- HOW TO RESOLVE IT?

   One way is to update the *name* attribute of the `<select>` tag:

   ```
   <select id="voices" name="voices">
   ```

   Or the javascript could be updated:

   ```
   var voicesDropdown = document.querySelector('[name="voices"]');
   ```
2. > how do I append two values to el.textContent? For eg. I want it to display `voices[i].name` and `voices[i].lang`

   The options properties can be referenced with setting the textContent property and appended using the [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) (i.e. `+`) or [String.concatenate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat).

   ```
   el.textContent = opt.name + ' - ' + opt.lang;
   ```

See this demonstrated in the snippet below.

```js
const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
let voices = [];
var voicesDropdown = document.querySelector('[name="voices"]');
const options = document.querySelector('[name="range"], [name="text"]'); // this selects the rate control bar, pitch bar and text area
const speakButton = document.querySelector('#speak');
const stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop');
msg.text = document.querySelector('[name="text"]').value;

function populateVoices() {
  voices = this.getVoices();

  for (var i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
    var opt = voices[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt.name + ' - ' + opt.lang;
    el.value = opt;
    voicesDropdown.appendChild(el);
  }

}
//when speechSynthesis loads , voiceschanged event occurs and populateVoices function is fired
speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', populateVoices);
```

```html
<div class="voiceinator">
  <h1> My Speech Synthesizer </h1>

  <select id="voices" name="voices">
        <option value="">Select a voice</option>
      </select>

  <label for="rate">Rate:</label>
  <input type="range" name="rate" value="1" min="0" max="3" step="0.1">

  <label for="pitch">Pitch:</label>
  <input type="range" name="pitch" min="0" max="2" step="0.1">

  <textarea name="text"> Hello there! </textarea>
  <button type="button" id="stop"> Stop! </button>
  <button type="button" id="speak"> Speak </button>
</div>
```